# robot_localization: How are the sensor measurements being fused?

Tags: ros, navigation, sensor-fusion, extended-kalman-filter, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was working with the robot_localization package for fusing encoder/IMU/GPS measurements. I wanted to know does the filter fuse the measurements in time? Is it a loosely-coupled fusion? It would be helpful if someone can explain the underlying algorithm for taking in the measurements for correction.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270004/robot_localization:-how-are-the-sensor-measurements-being-fused?/) by [gandhigauri](https://answers.ros.org/users/31758/gandhigauri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-08-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-01**:
ROS Answers has a lot of earlier questions about `robot_localization`. Have you tried taking a look at those and see whether they answer your questions? Using Google works best. Add `site:answers.ros.org` to your query text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [the documentation](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/robot_localization/html/index.html). That has a global overview of how things work, a link to the ROSCon15 talk by Tom and a reference to a paper describing the component.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gandhigauri](https://answers.ros.org/users/31758/gandhigauri/) on 2017-09-01**:
Thanks. I actually wanted some clarity/confirmation whether any sort of coupling happens between the measurements and their covariances before they are used for correction in the filter?